# What workflow should I use for JavaScript editing?

Tags: javascript, editing

**Warning: I have very little JavsScript experience.**

In my past programming experience, I usually have a standalone interpreter/compiler, a text editor and a command line to compile/run my software or my tests (I love test driven development). I really like it this way, since I have the feeling of being in complete control over the tools. However, editing JavaScript I need to put statements in a text file , open my web browser and click on reload. I don't feel comfortable with it, as I cannot really see what is going on (besides some alert boxes).

Can you suggest me (I'm on a Mac) another workflow? Perhaps with a debugger? Is there a standalone JavaScript interpreter?

Comment: Can I accept both answers as "answered my question"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) has a [javascript debugger](http://getfirebug.com/javascript),a console, and a [command line](http://getfirebug.com/commandline). I couldn't live without it.

Firebug is a firefox extension. They do have [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) for other browsers.

As far as workflow goes... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd> over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

[Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/), [Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565622%28VS.85%29.aspx), [Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html) and [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH8-SW1) all come with good debuggers built in (links go to information about the debuggers).

They are all modeled after [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), an extension for Firefox (and the existence of which is why Firefox doesn't have one built in).

Answer (score 1):

I would throw in validation there as well, use jslint either via one of the available command line tools, or via eg. Aptana which has builtin validation.
Setting up a simple build script is also preferable. I do it with all my projects and lets it handle validation, conditional code (debug versions etc) and minifying.

This http://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM/blob/master/build.xml is for instance the build setup for easyXDM. It does everything from pushing out new versions to the website to creating documentation and zip files..